flutter deep links not working with go router
I'm using go router in my flutter app to respond to deeplinks.
The flutter dev tool tells me that my deeplink are valid and when I run adb to manually activate a deep link i see:
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW '
          '-c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE '
          '-d "https://ivanhoehandyman.com.au/xero/auth_complete

Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW cat=[android.intent.category.BROWSABLE] dat=https://ivanhoehandyman.com.au/... }
Warning: Activity not started, intent has been delivered to currently running top-most instance.

Go router debug logs report the following routes:
[GoRouter] setting initial location null
[GoRouter] Full paths for routes:
           └─/ (HomeWithDrawer)
             ├─/error (ErrorScreen)
             ├─/jobs (HomeWithDrawer)
             ├─/customers (HomeWithDrawer)
             ├─/suppliers (HomeWithDrawer)
             ├─/shopping (HomeWithDrawer)
             ├─/packing (HomeWithDrawer)
             ├─/system/business (HomeWithDrawer)
             ├─/system/billing (HomeWithDrawer)
             ├─/system/contact (HomeWithDrawer)
             ├─/system/integration (HomeWithDrawer)
             ├─/system/about (HomeWithDrawer)
             ├─/system/backup (HomeWithDrawer)
             ├─/system/wizard (HomeWithDrawer)
             └─/xero/auth_complete (HomeWithDrawer)

The last one xer/auth_complete matches the link I'm triggering.
Here is my android manifest:

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="dev.onepub.handyman">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS" />
    <!-- so we can backup the db -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!-- backup_ruiles and data_extraction_rules required by oidc package -->
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true" android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules" android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:exported="true" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:taskAffinity="" android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!--
            Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
            the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
            while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
            to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI.
            -->
            <meta-data android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme" android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />
            <meta-data android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled" android:value="true" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="smsto" />
            </intent-filter>
            <!-- App Link:  deep linking -->
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="ivanhoehandyman.com.au" android:pathPrefix="/xero/auth_complete" />
                <data android:scheme="http" />
            </intent-filter>
            <!--
            Don't delete the meta-data below.
            This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
            -->
            <meta-data android:name="flutterEmbedding" android:value="2" />
        </activity>
    </application>
    <!--
    Required to query activities that can process text, see:
    https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility and
    https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT.
    
    In particular, this is used by the Flutter engine in io.flutter.plugin.text.ProcessTextPlugin.
    -->
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent>
        <!-- used by flutter_email_sender to send emails. -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
            <data android:scheme="mailto" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>


This is in a debug environment running on an emulator.
I had to manually enable the deeplink via going into the app info (on the emulator) and enable the link - this also seems to be a problem but one issue at a time.
I've setup my gradle build to sign the debug release - I'm assuming this is working but I'm not certain how to check this:
  signingConfigs {
        /// run tool/linux_setup.dart to create the keystore and
        /// add the key.properties file in the project root.
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }

        debug {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias.debug']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword.debug']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile.debug'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword.debug']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.release
        }
         debug {
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.debug
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        }
    }


I've been able to validate that my debug apk signature matches one of the sigs in my assetlinks.json
